# Error from IF statements Return type of one of the 'if' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am working on a pinescript script for TradeView. The idea is to use multiple conditions both for BUY and SELL signals. But there is something wrong with the SELL part. I get the following error message

Error at 39:0 Return type of one of the 'if' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s) (series[float]; series[float]; series[float]; series[float]; void; void; literal float)

Anyone who can see what is wrong with the script?

Thanks!

```
//@version=4
strategy("02-2219-1", overlay=true)

// Inputs
buyAmount = input(title="Buy Amount", type=input.float, defval = 1000)
ma_50 = input(title="Fast MA Length", type=input.integer, defval=50)
ma_200 = input(title="Slow MA Length", type=input.integer, defval=200)

// Calculations
hlc3 = (high + low + close) / 3
mfi_5 = mfi(hlc3, 5)
rsi_5 = rsi(close, 5)
ma_short = security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", sma(close, ma_50))
ma_long = security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", sma(close, ma_200))

// Variables
boughtCoins = 0.0
buyPrice = 0.0
float trailPrice = 0.0

// Buy Conditions
condition1 = ma_long < close
condition2 = ma_long < ma_short
condition3 = cross(mfi_5, 30)
condition4 = cross(mfi_5, 10)
condition5 = cross(rsi_5, 10)

// Buy
if (condition1 and condition2 and condition3) or (condition4) or (condition5) 
    if boughtCoins == 0 
        buyPrice := close
        boughtCoins := buyAmount / buyPrice
        strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, qty=boughtCoins)
    
// Sell
if not na(trailPrice) and close <= trailPrice * 0.99 
    strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty=boughtCoins, limit=close, comment="Price Increase by 1% trailing")
else if close > trailPrice or na(trailPrice)
    trailPrice := close * 0.99
else if not na(trailPrice) and close >= trailPrice * 1.005 
    strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty=boughtCoins, limit=close, comment="Price Decrease by 0.5% trailing")
else if close < trailPrice or na(trailPrice) 
    trailPrice := close * 1.005
else if (rsi_5 > 75) 
    strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty=boughtCoins, limit=close, comment="RSI greater than 75 in 5 min timeframe")
else if (mfi_5 > 80) 
    strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty=boughtCoins, limit=close, comment="MFI greater than 80 in 5 min timeframe")  

plot(trailPrice, title="Trail")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strategy.exit()` returns `void`

`trailPrice := close * 0.99` is a float

Please see the fix of your script below, I hope it makes everything clear. (You can use any values of the same type instead of `true`, like, e.g. `1`)

```
//@version=4
strategy("02-2219-1", overlay=true)

// Inputs
buyAmount = input(title="Buy Amount", type=input.float, defval = 1000)
ma_50 = input(title="Fast MA Length", type=input.integer, defval=50)
ma_200 = input(title="Slow MA Length", type=input.integer, defval=200)

// Calculations
hlc3 = (high + low + close) / 3
mfi_5 = mfi(hlc3, 5)
rsi_5 = rsi(close, 5)
ma_short = security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", sma(close, ma_50))
ma_long = security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", sma(close, ma_200))

// Variables
boughtCoins = 0.0
buyPrice = 0.0
float trailPrice = 0.0

// Buy Conditions
condition1 = ma_long < close
condition2 = ma_long < ma_short
condition3 = cross(mfi_5, 30)
condition4 = cross(mfi_5, 10)
condition5 = cross(rsi_5, 10)

// Buy
if (condition1 and condition2 and condition3) or (condition4) or (condition5) 
    if boughtCoins == 0 
        buyPrice := close
        boughtCoins := buyAmount / buyPrice
        strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, qty=boughtCoins)
    
// Sell
if not na(trailPrice) and close <= trailPrice * 0.99 
    strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty=boughtCoins, limit=close, comment="Price Increase by 1% trailing")
    true
else if close > trailPrice or na(trailPrice)
    trailPrice := close * 0.99
    true
else if not na(trailPrice) and close >= trailPrice * 1.005 
    strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty=boughtCoins, limit=close, comment="Price Decrease by 0.5% trailing")
    true
else if close < trailPrice or na(trailPrice) 
    trailPrice := close * 1.005
    true
else if (rsi_5 > 75) 
    strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty=boughtCoins, limit=close, comment="RSI greater than 75 in 5 min timeframe")
    true
else if (mfi_5 > 80) 
    strategy.exit("sell", "buy", qty=boughtCoins, limit=close, comment="MFI greater than 80 in 5 min timeframe")  
    true

plot(trailPrice, title="Trail")
```

Comment: Should also be noted that this requirement was relaxed in v5; there, the error will only appear if the if-else expression is assigned to a variable (which is not the case in the code above).
But automatic conversion requires the script to compile without errors, so one would still need to use this method to make a compilable script, then convert, then remove the placeholder returns like `type` and `1`

Comment: Were the requirement relaxed? I still see such errors, e.g.: https://imgbox.com/4WzjsfxI (just now)

Comment: The last statement in a function definition is implicitly considered the function's return. So in your case, the result of the whole statement is returned, and due to this the statement's branches must return the same type. You can add any placeholder return to the end of the function (e.g. just write `"placeholder_return"` in the very end) and  the error should disappear because the string will be considered the function's return instead.